# How do I remove the smell of sulphur from my elderflower wine?

Tags: wine, aroma

My wine is fully brewed. My hydrometer states that definitely. The issue is that it smells of eggs or similar. I do not want to put it in an aging barrel. So, how do I remove the smell of sulfur from my elderflower wine?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you have a hydrogen sulfide problem. There is a three steps I follow when I get this problem.

1. Give it time. Many times it will dissipate on it's own, especially with racking and introducing oxygen. But this doesn't always work.
2. Add some potassium metabisulfates (campden tablets). This sometimes will drive out the problem making the sulfides dissipate on their own.
3. Add copper sulfate. This is the last resort and most of the time I end up here. There are kits to help you figure out how much to add. Some people will just tell you to add some copper pipes to your wine but not nearly as effective as copper sulfate.

This is a common problem for amateur and professional wine makers. There is a good article [here](http://www.thevintnervault.com/index.php?p=w_m_tips&id=5781) but searching google will yield many results.

BTW, do not put it in the barrel. You might ruin the barrel. Take care of the problem first then put it in the barrel.

Comment: Ah, I've already bottled it. The corks are removable.

Comment: 'm going to try the Campden Tablets in the bottles.

Comment: Don't put a whole one in each bottle that is way too much. You will need to make a concentrated solution of meta and then syringe a small amount into each bottle. The other thing you could do is dump all  the bottles back into a carboy and then add the meta. I've done that before with good results. The meta will prevent most of the oxidization